# Error:Video format not supported ,occuring when trying to perform operations on captured frame and saving the video

Tags: opencv

I compiled this code which saves a video captured from webcam,in gray colour format.The video is getting saved at the end but not playing on any video player.Please help..

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

    # write the flipped frame
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    out.write(gray)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to save the video in grayscale format. For that you need to pass an additional parameter to `cv2.VideoWriter` as follows

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480), 0)
```

The last parameter is `0` because you are not saving color frames. Hope this solves your problem